# Is there any way to Open New Window For Each Item in Pyqt5 QlistWidget(Only Double clicked items)

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qlistwidget, qlistwidgetitem

**Open New Different Window for Each Double Clicked Item** in QlistWidget. I'm using QtDesigner and I created a New dialog window and connected to **DoubleClick Event** of QlistWidgetitem. When I double click the QListitem it opens a new window. But I need to open a New Window For each Item (entirely complete data in a new window).

Example- QlistWidget https://i.stack.imgur.com/StiEC.png

Here I have 2 items. When I double click Sugar I need to Open new Window that contain to Sugar Details.
After sugar I need to open BP and then I need to Open New Window About BP details. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Attach a function for the QListWidget's click slot. Then use new qwidgets instances for each click

Comment: Sure. @user662650